# Как лучше организовать структуру в бд?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

У меня есть такая задача на Laravel
Есть mysql таблица категорий в виде дерева (id,parent_id,title,level,queue) и есть пользователи,
нужно сделать чтобы у каждого пользователя была возможность отсортировать категории по своему усмотрению, но чтобы основная таблица категорий была неизменной.
Как это лучше сделать ?

Comment: отсортировать, это изменить parent_id ? тогда храниь таблицу связи `user_id, cat_id, parent_id`, выбирать через `select coalesce(xxx.parent_id, categories.parent_id) ..... LEFT JOIN xxx on xxx.user_id = ? and categories.id = cat_id`

Comment: нет, отсротировать чтобы значение queue при построении дерева  для каждого пользователся было своим

Comment: и мы тут догадаться должны, что `queue` это параметр для сортировки? Сути дела не меняет, таблица связи будет `user_id, cat_id, q`

Comment: зы: это вы так "очередность" перевели что ли? явно для этих целей не используется.

Comment: Создавайте таблицу `(user_id, node_id, sorting_order)`.